# Google cloud pub/sub autoconfigure does not work in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working on a spring boot project that use **google cloud pub/sub** for the communication between microservices.
We manage the google cloud pub/sub configuration in a seperate spring boot project(library).

I had the following problem when I try to get/inject **PubSubConsumerServiceImpl** from library in my **microservice**.

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.myCompany.myproject.messaging.adapter.PubSubConsumerServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate' that could not be found.

Action:   
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**PubSubConsumerServiceImpl**

```
import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate;
@Slf4j
@Service
public class PubSubConsumerServiceImpl implements ConsumerConnector {

    private final PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;
    private final MessagingConfigParams configParams;

    public PubSubConsumerServiceImpl(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate, ObjectMapper objectMapper,
                                     MessagingConfigParams configParams){
        this.pubSubTemplate = pubSubTemplate;
        this.mapper = objectMapper;
        this.configParams = configParams;
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(String subscriptionName, Consumer<OutboxEvent> consumer) {
       //subscription code
    }
}
```

In the root package of the library we have this configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MessagingConfigParams.class)
public class PubsubAutoConfiguration{
}
```

We have spring.factories to enable the spring boot autoconfiguration:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  com.myCompany.myproject.messaging.PubsubAutoConfiguration
```

We have the following dependencies in the build.gradle file

```
implementation("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:2.0.4")
```

we are using spring Boot Version = '2.4.2'

I tried to add this annotation ***@Import(GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class)*** to the **PubsubAutoConfiguration** class.

And I tried also to inject the bean PubSubTemplate inside the PubsubAutoConfiguration :

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate(PubSubPublisherTemplate pubSubPublisherTemplate,
            PubSubSubscriberTemplate pubSubSubscriberTemplate) {
        return new PubSubTemplate(pubSubPublisherTemplate, pubSubSubscriberTemplate);
    }
```

but I still have the same error

Comment: Can you do it as the [library](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-gcp-pubsub#:~:text=if%20you%E2%80%99re%20using%20Gradle) says if you are using a gradle file? Instead of using `implementation` use `compile` in the gradle file.

Comment: Did you get this working? I am getting similar issue and couldn't find nay solution as such.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to use

```
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub
```

instead of

```
com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub
```

Comment: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub hasn't been updated since Apr 22, 2021. Does anyone know whether this is still the best answer?